# Change default indentation in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2022, indentation

How do I change the default indentation in Visual Studio?

I want it to always use tabs instead of spaces.

Everywhere I've looked it either doesn't tell me how to make tabs the default or is several years out of date.

EDIT:
Bit embarrassing, I already had the issue solved. The little widget in the bottom right still said it was using spaces, even though it was using tabs. I was pretty frustrated by the point I found those settings so I didn't test if they worked (although it is a bit strange to me that the widget in the bottom right wouldn't update).

Comment: What _have_ you looked at? I don't want to re-recommend the same things you might have already seen.

Comment: Because you tagged c#, my settings below are specific to c#. You can try it to see if it meets your needs.

Comment: While you are at it, change tab size to an indent of 2. 4 is such a waste. ;)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Environment:VS 2022 Community C#

Options->c#->Tabs->Keep tabs:

[image]

[image]

Comment: You can also use a `.editorconfig` file: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/create-portable-custom-editor-options?view=vs-2022

Answer (score 1):

In Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2022 you can do like this.

- Choose "**Options...**" from the "**Tools**" menu.
  [image: Tools -> Options...]
- Search for "**Tabs**" in the **Search box** and choose "**Keep tabs**" in the **"Tab"-section**.
  [image]